# How to type `this` when converting to Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm working in a Typescript Vue project with Leaflet. I've found some code to lazy-load map markers, but it was written in Javascript. It works fine, but I get VSCode errors and compiler warnings because `this` is not typed. How do I type `this`?

Update 1: I got the first type to resolve using @aplet123 suggestion below. But I can't figure out the second one on `this._updateIconVisibility`. I think this is because I'm actually using the function to extend the existing functionality (i.e. `_updateIconVisibility` does not actually exist on a type). So now what do I do? I suspect it is best practice to just create a custom class with the methods I need, but I don't know if it is actually more common to provide maybe an anonymous object or something else...

```
L.Marker.addInitHook(function (this: L.Marker) {
    this.on(
        'add',
        function () {
            this._updateIconVisibility = function () {
                var map = this._map,
                    isVisible = map.getBounds().contains(this.getLatLng()),
                    wasVisible = this._wasVisible,
                    icon = this._icon,
                    iconParent = this._iconParent,
                    shadow = this._shadow,
                    shadowParent = this._shadowParent

                // remember parent of icon
                if (!iconParent) {
                    iconParent = this._iconParent = icon.parentNode
                }
                if (shadow && !shadowParent) {
                    shadowParent = this._shadowParent = shadow.parentNode
                }

                // add/remove from DOM on change
                if (isVisible != wasVisible) {
                    if (isVisible) {
                        iconParent.appendChild(icon)
                        if (shadow) {
                            shadowParent.appendChild(shadow)
                        }
                    } else {
                        iconParent.removeChild(icon)
                        if (shadow) {
                            shadowParent.removeChild(shadow)
                        }
                    }

                    this._wasVisible = isVisible
                }
            }

            // on map size change, remove/add icon from/to DOM
            this._map.on(
                'resize moveend zoomend',
                this._updateIconVisibility,
                this
            )
            this._updateIconVisibility()
        },
        this
    )
})
```

[image: VSCode error]

Comment: Give the function a typed argument called `this` (it's not an actual argument and won't be compiled into the resulting javascript, it's just to notate the `this` type).

Comment: it has to do with your project configuration https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html update your tsconfig.json and set `strict: true`

Comment: @Aplet123 Thanks that works for the first instance. I've updated my question. Additionally, if I run into a circumstance later where the function had required arguments, would this still work? would I just pass those arguments after the `this` argument and they will be in the correct order?

Comment: @BooklynDadCore Thanks, I already have set `strict: true` in my .tsconfig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not ultra-familiar with your environment (Vue, etc.) but I was able to construct the following file that eliminates the errors and hopefully demonstrates the way forward. It could likely be improved if I knew more.

The key is really describing your `this` types at each step. So I created a bit of scaffolding, created a type `MyObject` to describe the decorations you're implementing, and then declared `this` to be of type `MyObject` at the appropriate spot.

See below, and let me know if there's stuff that's not clear.

```
//  Scaffolding to account for things from the environment
namespace L {
    type handler = () => void

    type target = object;

    export type on = (types: string, handler: handler, target: target) => void

    export interface Marker {
        on: on
    }
}

const L = {
    Marker: {
        addInitHook: function(f: (this: L.Marker) => void) {
            //  just here because your code must be supplying it
        }
    }
}

//  A type to add to your code
namespace L {
    export type MyObject = {
        _updateIconVisibility: () => void,
        _map: {
            on: on
        }
    }
}

//  Your code above, now with no objection from the TypeScript compiler
L.Marker.addInitHook(function (this: L.Marker) {
    this.on(
        'add',
        function (this: L.MyObject) {
            this._updateIconVisibility = function () {
                var map = this._map,
                    isVisible = map.getBounds().contains(this.getLatLng()),
                    wasVisible = this._wasVisible,
                    icon = this._icon,
                    iconParent = this._iconParent,
                    shadow = this._shadow,
                    shadowParent = this._shadowParent

                // remember parent of icon
                if (!iconParent) {
                    iconParent = this._iconParent = icon.parentNode
                }
                if (shadow && !shadowParent) {
                    shadowParent = this._shadowParent = shadow.parentNode
                }

                // add/remove from DOM on change
                if (isVisible != wasVisible) {
                    if (isVisible) {
                        iconParent.appendChild(icon)
                        if (shadow) {
                            shadowParent.appendChild(shadow)
                        }
                    } else {
                        iconParent.removeChild(icon)
                        if (shadow) {
                            shadowParent.removeChild(shadow)
                        }
                    }

                    this._wasVisible = isVisible
                }
            }

            // on map size change, remove/add icon from/to DOM
            this._map.on(
                'resize moveend zoomend',
                this._updateIconVisibility,
                this
            )
            this._updateIconVisibility()
        },
        this
    )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

David's answer led me to just define an interface which contains members for the extended functionality. It ends up looking like this:

```
interface LazyMarker extends Marker {
    _wasVisible: boolean
    _icon: ((Node & ParentNode) | null) & Icon
    _iconParent: (Node & ParentNode) | null
    _shadowParent: (Node & ParentNode) | null
    _updateIconVisibility(): void
}

// this hook makes the markers lazy load
// increases performance of map scrolling/moving
L.Marker.addInitHook(function (this: LazyMarker) {
    this.on(
        'add',
        function (this: LazyMarker) {
            this._updateIconVisibility = function (this: LazyMarker) {
                var map = this._map,
                    isVisible = map.getBounds().contains(this.getLatLng()),
                    wasVisible = this._wasVisible,
                    icon = this._icon,
                    iconParent = this._iconParent,
                    shadow = this._shadow,
                    shadowParent = this._shadowParent

                // remember parent of icon
                if (!iconParent) {
                    iconParent = this._iconParent = icon.parentNode
                }
                if (shadow && !shadowParent) {
                    shadowParent = this._shadowParent = shadow.parentNode
                }

                // add/remove from DOM on change
                if (iconParent != null && isVisible != wasVisible) {
                    if (isVisible) {
                        iconParent.appendChild(icon)
                        if (shadowParent != null && shadow) {
                            shadowParent.appendChild(shadow)
                        }
                    } else {
                        iconParent.removeChild(icon)
                        if (shadowParent != null && shadow) {
                            shadowParent.removeChild(shadow)
                        }
                    }

                    this._wasVisible = isVisible
                }
            }

            // on map size change, remove/add icon from/to DOM
            this._map.on(
                'resize moveend zoomend',
                this._updateIconVisibility,
                this
            )
            this._updateIconVisibility()
        },
        this
    )
})
```